# Behaviour of memcpy when pointers are identical

Tags: c

I know that `memcpy(dest, src, n)` has undefined behaviour when the regions of memory pointed to by `src` and `dest` overlap. But does this cover the case where `dest == src`? I know of no implementation of `memcpy` that would fail in this case - but what does the standard say about it? This comes up when (e.g.) copying (large) elements of an array in a loop - do I have to ensure `i != j` when doing `memcpy(arr + i, arr + j, sizeof(*arr))`?

Comment: Yes, it's still undefined behavior (and a violation of the `restrict` contract that `memcpy` has since C99) - it's clearly stated in the reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy (Also the standard is freely available, you could just have looked it up yourself)

Comment: Ah thanks for the link, the first few results I got when I searched it (including the manpage) do not mention the `restrict` keyword. I will be sure to add `i != j` where appropriate

Comment: If the pointers are the same, they obviously overlap completely.

Comment: Imagine a hypothetical implementation that zeroes out the destination memory before copying anything -- nothing in the specification prohibits this.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, this is very clear to me now

Comment: any reason not to use memmove ?